# How can I recursively find a directory by name and delete its contents (including all sub-directories and files) while keeping the directory itself?

Tags: command-line, find, rm

**Given**:

1. I have a tree structure with folders `EmptyMe` on different levels
2. `EmptyMe` directories contain sub-directories and files

**Required**:

1. Empty contents of `EmptyMe` directories (**including** their sub-directories), while keeping those directories (not deleting them).

**Question**:

What's the Unix command to recursively find all `EmptyMe` directories from current level and delete all of their contents (including sub-directories), while keeping `EmptyMe` directories on the disc?

**My attempt**:

```
$ find . -name 'EmptyMe' -type d -exec rm -- {} +
rm: cannot remove `./a/b/c/d/EmptyMe': Is a directory
```

As you can see, that command attempted to remove `EmptyMe`, as opposed to its contents.

Comment: Nest it maybe ? `find . -name 'EmptyMe' -type d -exec find {} -type f -delete \;` Let me know if you want this as actual answer

Comment: That didn't remove sub-directories of `EmptyMe`.

Comment: @Sergiy You need `-mindepth 1` for the nested command, and remove `-type f` cause OP wants to remove directories too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Test run:

```
find . -path '*/EmptyMe/*'
```

Real deletion:

```
find . -path '*/EmptyMe/*' -delete
```

`-path '*/EmptyMe/*'` means *match all items that are in a directory called `EmptyMe`*.

Answer (score 3):

One option that can be used is to nest the commands:

```
find . -type d -name 'EmptyMe'  -exec find {} -mindepth 1 -delete \;
```

The outer `find -type d -name 'EmptyMe'` locates the required directories, and runs the inner `find` command via `-exec ... \;`. The inner command descends into the found directory (referenced via `{}` ) and since we're using `-delete` flag here, it should follow depth-first search, removing files and then subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it gives errors if `EmptyMe` directories are empty.

```
find . -name 'EmptyMe' -type d -exec sh -c 'rm -r -- "$1"/*' sh {} \;
```

Error example:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘./EmptyMe/*’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you please update the accepted answer with the fix to avoid this error?

Comment: @temuri They're different solutions, so i put them in different answers

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear which solution exactly would avoid "No such file or directory" error. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @temuri Oh, gotcha. Sergiy's answer and my other one both avoid this error because they don't assume the `EmptyMe` directories have contents.