# Running a python script for different files in subdirectories

Tags: python

I have a main folder named "simulations". In this folder I have 250 different folders named with year-month-day as: "19902010" "20040512" etc... These dates are random without any specific pattern but always in the form "year-month-day". 
In each "year-month-day" folder I have a folder named "outfiles" in which are contained the files that I have to change automatically. 
How can I run this automatically?
Hope to have a reply!!
Thanks in advance!
Silvia

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have the main folder named "simulations". In this folder I have 250 different folders named with year-month-day as: "19902010" "20040512" etc... These date are random without any specific pattern but always in the form "year-month-day". In each folder I have a folder named "outfiles" in which are contained my files.

Comment: The files inside the folder "outfiles" are named as "c_001_000001.grd", "c_001_000002.grd", "c_001_000003.grd", and so on. So, I have to run my script automatically for each of thiese .grd files and save them as "ppm_c_001_000001.grd" and so on.. So it is quite complicate!!

Comment: Please **[edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1209569/edit)** your question and add all the new information **in the question**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run your Python script (let me call it `myScript.py`) on each `*.grd` file in all subfolders (recursively) of a given folder, then [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) is the right command to do it:

```
find . -name '*.grd' -exec python myScript.py {} \;
```

This command recursively finds each file in the given path<sup>1</sup> with the name matching `*.grd` and calls `python myScript.py <found .grd file>`<sup>2</sup> for each found file. You can test this by adding `echo` right after `-exec`, then it will just print the commands.

---

<sup>1</sup> I used `.` in my example and you can use it, too, if you `cd` to the specified folder first. Otherwise, you can use any appropriate relative or absolute path here.

<sup>2</sup> If your script is [executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-run-from-a-termi) and has the correct [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), you can leave out `python` and call `myScript.py` directly.

### See also

- [How to Search for Files Recursively into Subdirectories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307876/how-to-search-for-files-recursively-into-subdirectories)
- [How can I recursively find a directory by name and delete its contents (including all sub-directories and files) while keeping the directory itself?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066026/how-can-i-recursively-find-a-directory-by-name-and-delete-its-contents-includin)